# RuntimeError: In draw_glyphs_to_bitmap: Could not convert glyph to bitmap (error code 0x62)

Tags: api, graph, twitter, networkx, tweepy

I am studying tweepy and networkx to see the relationships between Twitter users. I have created Graphs with my users and followers but when I try to plot them I get: `RuntimeError: In draw_glyphs_to_bitmap: Could not convert glyph to bitmap (error code 0x62)`. Did I do something wrong? I couldn't find the answer on the internet.

The code I have:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

my_user = api.get_user(screen_name='my_user')

my_followers = []

for friend in my_user.friends():
   my_followers.append(friend.screen_name)

G = nx.Graph()
first_node = G.add_node(my_user)

for user in my_followers:
   G.add_node(user)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show() #Here is where I get the error
```